# Preventing a message: ga is not defined

Tags: google-analytics

I have installed Google Analytics via Google Tag Manager.
Then I would like to ingorm Google Analytics of some events.

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits

```
function createGa(){
    ga('create', 'UA-209160399-1', 'auto');
}
ga('send', {
    hitType: 'event',
    eventCategory: 'form',
    eventAction: 'submit',
    eventLabel: "content_category"
  });
```

**The problem**

This causes an error:

```
createGa();
```

> ga is undefined.

Now I use like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(createGa, 1000);
}
```

As for the logic, for me it seems reasonable: let the document be rady in 1 second and then further delay caused by setTimeout. In 2-3 seconds a user will never be able to submit a form or something.

Could you tell me whether setTimeout is reasonable here? What troubles me is that I've never read about this in the documentation. This setTimeout is inspired by what is written in the doc by the link above. But it is not exactly what is written there. It is an analogy.

Could you comment?

Comment: This does not seem to make a lot of sense - if you already have installed GA via GTM you do not need to do a ga create call, and you would not call ga send directly - instead you would either push an event to the datalayer on form submit, or use the form submit trigger within GTM.

Comment: I have tried. Without the creation of ga, events don't appear in GA.

As for any other possibility to inform GA of something like phone click or something, I don't know. In case of a form it may be a "Thank you" url. But I prefer AJAX forms and JavaScript Events as goals in GA.